# Vue.js e2E tests Nightwatch : anyway to run the test with a specific config.test.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, environment-variables

I am currently running my e2e test w Nightwatch..
In production, the app mutation.js file setup some constants from a config file

```
 import { WORKING_TIME, RESTING_TIME, KITTEN_TIME } from '../config'
```

I wonder if there is anyway to setup these constants from other config files depending upon the processing environment  ( production, development, test )

```
  <if production>
    import { WORKING_TIME, RESTING_TIME, KITTEN_TIME } from '../config'
  <if development>
    import { WORKING_TIME, RESTING_TIME, KITTEN_TIME } from '../config.dev'
   <if test>
   import { WORKING_TIME, RESTING_TIME, KITTEN_TIME } from '../config.test'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to import modules using if / else ...

As the data I need to import according to the NODE_ENV are constant variables, I resolved to set them up directly into the imported file :

**config.js**

```
let coeff = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing' ? 0.1 : 1

export const WORKING_TIME = coeff * 60
export const RESTING_TIME = coeff * 60
export const KITTEN_TIME = 5 // each kitten is visible for 5 secs
```